# Extracting git hash and use it in gradle

Tags: git, gradle, groovy, continuous-integration, teamcity

I've define a method which returns the git hash as string:

```
def getGitHash() {
    return ext.githash='git log --pretty=format:%h -1'.execute().text.trim()
}
```

If i build with TeamCity 9.x this method returns an empty string. Seems inside the build environment it is not possible to execute binaries.

Thank you for suggestions to fix it.

Comment: How do you call this task?

Comment: android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            ...
            versionName "0.1." + getBuildSystemNumber() + "-develop (" + getGitHash() + ")"
}

(posting code as comment seems difficulty)

Comment: Have you tried to use ${ getGitHash()} ?

Comment: No, but this code works on jenkins fine. Tried it, but gives syntax error.

Comment: Tried the full path to git? If that doesn't work, it's probably throwing an error, so you'll have to change your code to capture the error stream too

Comment: Tried the absolute patch, checked the PATH environment varialble from the agent. No success so far. I achieved my goal in a different way. But TC seems to block those "string executions".